Overriding pip package
I am trying to setup Octoprint on a new orangepi 3b board. It has been a bit problematic.
One problem is about access to gpio for all the existing plugins. The standard RPi.GPIO python library does not work on the orangepi 3B, but there is an OPi.GPIO that does, and should be - at least a partial - drop in replacement for RPi.GPIO.
So I would like to have the OPi.GPIO package appear as RPi.GPIO, so it will be used instead. This way all the existing plugins for OctoPrint could be used without me having to create special versions.
Is this possible?
I have tried looking into pip, but as far as I can see from docs and google it can't be done via pip.

Indeed, it has nothing to do with pip. You might need to do what is called "monkey patch" or something like that, I am not sure.

I'd probably just try slapping an RPi/GPIO.py in your octoprint's virtualenv's site-packages directory containing from OPi.GPIO import *...

Thanks. I tried in various ways to replace the content of the RPi dir, but I didnt succeed.
